# Ubuntu Xenial - Docker Hello World Freezes Until Forced (Ctrl-C) Stop

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker

I was trying to follow docker official installation guideline [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/#install-from-a-package).

It was all good until I hit `docker run hello-world` and also `docker pull hello-world` which resulted into the following

```
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from library/hello-world
5b0f327be733: Extracting [==================================================>]     974B/974B
```

my `docker version` output:

```
Client:
 Version:      17.06.2-ce
 API version:  1.30
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   cec0b72
 Built:        Tue Sep  5 20:00:17 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.06.2-ce
 API version:  1.30 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   cec0b72
 Built:        Tue Sep  5 19:59:11 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: false
```

I am still quite new to docker so may be i have missed configuring something? For Xenial, I think so far my steps have been okay?

Regards,

Comment: Kill this command and run `journalctl -f -n10` in one terminal and `docker run hello-world`. See if you find any errors in the`journalctl` logs terminal

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.